# Find the next double value in an array

Tags: java

I'm programming a simulation of a Radio Tuner. Now I want to have a method that can loop through an array or arraylist, by steps of 0.05MHz. At the moment I have a array with my favorite radio frequencies, and the loop has to be stop if a frequency is found.

```
public static double favFrequencies [] = {89.8, 91.5, 93.7, 95.1, 97.7, 99.2, 100.7, 101.2, 101.7, 102.7, 103.0, 104.4};
```

At the moment I have the following code:

```
public static void searchDown()
{
    double startFrequency = Math.round(currentFreq * 100);
    double maxFrequency = Math.round(87.80 * 100);
    for (double f = startFrequency; f > maxFrequency; f -= 5) {
        //boolean nextFavFound = false;
        if (f < 8785)
        {
            f = 10800;
        }
        for (double f2 : favFrequencies) {
            if (f / 100 == f2) {
                nextFavFound = true;
                //break;
            }
        }
        if (nextFavFound) {
            currentFreq = f /100;
            RadioGUI.lblFreq.setText("FM " + Double.toString(currentFreq)+ "Mhz");
            System.out.println("next favFrequency: " + f / 100);
            nextFavFound = false;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

It does work quite well, but when I run the method again, it will not work with the new outputted value of the first time.

Comment: I'll use a [For Loop](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html) compare the frequency vs mine and if I find it then break from the statement. [HERE](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/branch.html) is a good example of that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will run into precision problems when using `for`-loops and an `double` increment with decimal places. One pragmatic approach for your problem would be multiplying by a factor of 100.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    double startFrequency = Math.round(88 * 100);
    double maxFrequency = Math.round(108 * 100);
    for (double f = startFrequency; f < maxFrequency; f += 5) {
        boolean nextFavFound = false;
        for (double f2 : favFrequencies) {
            if (f / 100 == f2) {
                nextFavFound = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (nextFavFound) {
            System.out.println("next favFrequency: " + f / 100);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I slightly added your code and now it returns the next favFrequency that is found after the current  frequency. When I run the method again, it's returning the same value again, again and again.

Answer (score 0):

Start with a simple `for loop`, initiate `i` at whatever the minimum frequency is, stop at the max frequency and increment by 0.05 (make sure i is a double). Then, you can check at each step:

```
boolean containsFav = false;
for(double i=80.00;i<110.00;i=i+0.05){
    if(Arrays.asList(favFrequencies).contains(i)){
        containsFav = true;
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you actually let this run? It loops all the way through 110 and never finds a favourite frequency. On my machine, at least.

Comment: I got the same result. It loops all throuh in my case 108 and never found something.
My if statement is as follow:  if(Arrays.asList(favFrequencies).contains(Math.round(i * 20.0) / 20.0))

Comment: currently reading: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html

Answer (score 0):

With the following code I fixed my problem.

```
public static void searchUp()
{
    currentFreq +=0.05;
    double startFrequency = Math.round(currentFreq * 100);
    double maxFrequency = Math.round(108 * 100);
    for (double f = startFrequency; f < maxFrequency; f += 5) {
        //boolean nextFavFound = false;
        if (f > 10790)
        {
            f = 8780;
        }
        for (double f2 : favFrequencies) {
            if (f / 100 == f2) {
                nextFavFound = true;
                //break;
            }
        }
        if (nextFavFound) {
            currentFreq = f /100;
            RadioGUI.lblFreq.setText("FM " + Double.toString(currentFreq)+ "Mhz");
            //System.out.println("next favFrequency: " + f / 100);
            nextFavFound = false;
            //currentFreq +=0.05;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```